# Mapping bokeh RangeSlider output into different labels

Tags: python, bokeh

I have RangeSlider defined as follows,

```py
slider = RangeSlider(start=0, end=5, value=(0,1), step=1, title="Time")
```

Is there a way to change the output of the slider so that instead of getting the values 0 to 5, I am able to 'map' these values into some other labels. For instance, whenever the range is 0...4, I get instead t0...t4.

I have not been able to find any information in the bokeh documentation to do this. I am just wondering whether it is at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would appear that this is possible but the answer is not simple, and requires going deep into bokeh and javascript. I have found a some mention of this possibility in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmI1foA0MZc) (see video @ min 25:30) which lead me to this [file](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/sphinx/source/docs/user_guide/examples/extensions_example_widget.py) in the bokeh repo.